# Parsing dynamic webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I need to parse dynamic webpage (YouTube playlist). It has a button "MORE" at the end of the playlist to add more clips to the page. I have a script for parsing and it works but only with first 100 clips, because `cheerio` doesn't work with dynamic pages. I know that I should use `phantomjs` but I can't understand how to deal with it.

I simulated the click on this button and what's next? How to "reload" page for extracting new html code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you click on the "more" button, then you probably expect something to happen on the current page. You don't need to reload (although PhantomJS has a reload function). Instead you should wait a bit before getting the page source.

Comment: @ArtjomB. So, how to wait a bit? :D

Answer (score 1):

You have no need to parse pages. Please check Youtube API https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript